# /dev/video0 : invalid argument

Tags: kernel, device, webcam, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Why I am not able to read this file. I tried reading this file with cat as :

```
cat /dev/video0
```

But it says

```
cat: /dev/video0 : invalid arguments
```

Similarly, if I try to use dd as :

```
dd if=/dev/video0 ~/vid
```

It still is not able to read it.

Note that video0 is the device file for my webcam.

Comment: maybe the output of *dmesg* can be useful

Comment: @Federico dmesg gives no output on executing cat /dev/video0

Comment: Insufficient privileges? IME shell-tools don't always give the error messages you might expect.  Try `strace` and see precisely what happens when the `read()` sys-call fails.

Comment: This device file is used to configure the underlying webcam, camera or sensor driver i.e. configuring resolution (width, height and bpp), color modes(RGB, YUV) etc.. I think we can't read any information from this device file. Most of the configurations are done using ioctl calls.

Answer (score 7):

In such cases, one way to find out more is to run the command in *strace*

```
strace cat /dev/video0
```

which will show more details of the point of failure:

```
....
open("/dev/video0", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0660, st_rdev=makedev(81, 0), ...}) = 0
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, 0x2379000, 65536)               = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
....
```

which in my case seems to be saying that my /dev/video0 device does not support the required operation: so in this case, 'cat' is trying to read 64k bytes from the device.

However, I found that using nc (netcat) instead of cat did work for this purpose:

```
nc -l 1234 </dev/video0
```

With a corresponding:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1234 | mplayer tv://device=/dev/stdin
```

to display locally; an SSH tunnel port would also work here.

Comment: nc -l -p 1234 ?

Comment: No @moof2k, read the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

>>>
-p source_port
Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
dd if=/dev/video0 of=~/movie.mpg
```

Then

```
vlc movie.mpg
```

But I'm using a PVRUSB2 mpg encoder/decoder as the source.

In your dd invocation you might consider a redirect, ">", of using the "of" construct.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the show function for the device node "video0" you created in your driver might be wrong.

Give an example in below.

```c
static DEVICE_ATTR(video0, S_IRUGO|S_IWUSR|S_IWGRP|S_IWOTH, video0_show, video0_store);

static ssize_t video0_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf);

static ssize_t video0_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf, size_t count);
```

When you cat the device node "video0" at runtime, it calls the "video0_show" function to print something.
The error message "cat: /dev/video0 : invalid arguments" means that the arguments for the video0_show function is wrong. You should debug the driver.